# Create, build and run solution (two projects: library and tests) with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible now to create solution with Visual Studio Code editor (on Windows, assuming that potentially I should be able to run it on Mac)?

What I need:

```
App
|- Library (classes, business logic)
|- Tests
```

Later I want to add more projects to this solution, like asp.net website, helper services, etc. Right now wanna focus on business logic, tests and POCO only (with C#).

Is the future here already? And how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the easiest is to target DNX (the cross platform runtime) and to use the DNX project system (project.json). A good read is this: https://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dnx/overview.html

A good (but big) example is OmniSharp (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn) which is developed by multiple people on all different platforms.

Comment: Thanks. Installed DNX, trying to figure out how to create solution and add two projects: library and tests. Not an easy task, docs are not there yet

Comment: Yeah, it is early. Basically a project is defined by having a project.json. That lists dependencies to nugget and other projects. For instance, this is a small (sub-)project from omnisharp (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/src/OmniSharp.Stdio/project.json)  and this the test project for it: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/tests/OmniSharp.Stdio.Tests/project.json#L7